# Why 'terraform import' did not read my configuration?

Tags: go, terraform, terraform0.12+, hashicorp, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm building a Terraform plugin/provider using Go. I have the following in my schema ([link](https://github.com/civo/terraform-provider-civo/blob/e82f7ce8bc846c5b7bc4040a60aecc974d42a378/civo/resource_kubernetes_cluster_nodepool.go#L53-L55)):

```
Importer: &schema.ResourceImporter{
  State: resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport,
}
```

And this is the function ([link](https://github.com/civo/terraform-provider-civo/blob/e82f7ce8bc846c5b7bc4040a60aecc974d42a378/civo/resource_kubernetes_cluster_nodepool.go#L213-L238)):

```
func resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport(d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) ([]*schema.ResourceData, error) {
    apiClient := m.(*civogo.Client)

    clusterID, nodePoolID, err := utils.ResourceCommonParseID(d.Id())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    log.Printf("[INFO] retriving the node pool %s", nodePoolID)
    resp, err := apiClient.GetKubernetesCluster(clusterID)
    if err != nil {
        if resp != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    d.Set("cluster_id", resp.ID)
    for _, v := range resp.Pools {
        if v.ID == nodePoolID {
            d.Set("num_target_nodes", v.Count)
            d.Set("target_nodes_size", v.Size)
        }
    }

    return []*schema.ResourceData{d}, nil
}
```

When I added these debug lines at the top of function above, the results (`reg` and `ok`) were empty and `false`:

```
reg, ok := d.GetOk("region")
log.Printf("resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport reg %+v\n", reg)
log.Println("resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport ok", ok)
log.Println("resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport d.Get()", d.Get("region"))
if !ok {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("[ERR] Please provide a region in your import configuration")
}
```

Traces:

```
$ echo $TF_LOG
INFO
$ tf import civo_kubernetes_node_pool.my_pool 1b272dc1-836c-4ea7-8f20-4569f20ddbdd:d0c22622-54b3-41c2-9eae-24591737d5ad
2021-08-12T11:22:30.552+0800 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.0.3
2021-08-12T11:22:30.552+0800 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.16.4
2021-08-12T11:22:30.552+0800 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"/usr/local/bin/terraform", "import", "civo_kubernetes_node_pool.my_pool", "1b272dc1-836c-4ea7-8f20-4569f20ddbdd:d0c22622-54b3-41c2-9eae-24591737d5ad"}
2021-08-12T11:22:30.552+0800 [INFO]  Loading CLI configuration from /Users/zulh/.terraformrc
2021-08-12T11:22:30.553+0800 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"import", "civo_kubernetes_node_pool.my_pool", "1b272dc1-836c-4ea7-8f20-4569f20ddbdd:d0c22622-54b3-41c2-9eae-24591737d5ad"}
2021-08-12T11:22:30.629+0800 [INFO]  Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
2021-08-12T11:22:30.631+0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-08-12T11:22:31.284+0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-civo_v99.0.0: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-08-12T11:22:31.283+0800
2021-08-12T11:22:31.358+0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-08-12T11:22:31.404+0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-civo_v99.0.0: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-08-12T11:22:31.404+0800
2021-08-12T11:22:31.478+0800 [WARN]  ValidateProviderConfig from "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/civo/civo\"]" changed the config value, but that value is unused
civo_kubernetes_node_pool.my_pool: Importing from ID "1b272dc1-836c-4ea7-8f20-4569f20ddbdd:d0c22622-54b3-41c2-9eae-24591737d5ad"...
2021-08-12T11:22:31.479+0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-civo_v99.0.0: 2021/08/12 11:22:31 resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport reg: timestamp=2021-08-12T11:22:31.479+0800      <-- this line
2021-08-12T11:22:31.479+0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-civo_v99.0.0: 2021/08/12 11:22:31 resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport ok false: timestamp=2021-08-12T11:22:31.479+0800 <-- this line
2021-08-12T11:22:31.479+0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-civo_v99.0.0: 2021/08/12 11:22:31 resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport d.Get(): timestamp=2021-08-12T11:22:31.479+0800  <-- this line
╷
│ Error: [ERR] Please provide a region in your import configuration
│
│
╵
```

The problem is, I have added the `region` in my Terraform configuration *main.tf* file (and saved it) before I run the `tf import` command above. Here is my main.tf file:

```
resource "civo_kubernetes_cluster" "my_cluster" {
    name = "my-cluster"
}

resource "civo_kubernetes_node_pool" "my_pool" {
    region = "LON1" <-- this line
}
```

Why my Terraform plugin/provider sees the region as empty?

From my understanding, Terraform will first read the configuration file before running the import logic. Am I wrong? Did I miss something here?

---

For the sake of completeness, I'm using Terraform v1.0.3 and this is my *provider.tf* file...

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    civo = {
      source  = "civo/civo"
      version = "99.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "civo" {
    token = “my-api-key-here”
}
```

...where `99.0.0` is the version that I built for my testing only. The latest/prod version for this provider is [0.10.9](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/civo/civo/latest) when I posted this question.

Comment: Did you require a `region` in your provider schema? `import` mostly references the provider for this kind of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`Importer.State` function does not have access to existing config, it is provided an empty resource state with `id` - [see code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/e8b4b75e8cac67434439e4f71f574b5b26279c0f/helper/schema/provider.go#L364-L366).

As a workaround you can allow passing `region` to import command through underscore (or any symbol that does not conflict with symbols in ids or region names), like so:

```sh
terraform import civo_kubernetes_node_pool.my_pool <poolid>_<region>
```

And handle this in you importer function:

```golang
func resourceKubernetesClusterNodePoolImport(d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) ([]*schema.ResourceData, error) {
    apiClient := m.(*civogo.Client)

    // extract id and region from provided string
    parts := strings.Split(d.Id(), "_")
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        return nil, errors.New("To import a pool, use the format {pool_id}_{region}")
    }

    poolId := parts[0]
    region := parts[1]

    // Set new ID for resource
    d.SetId(poolId)

    // Set region
    d.Set("region", region)

    // Do the rest of the import

    ...
}
```